# Find TEAM pairs highest position ( lowers number )

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following sheet:

[image]

Where I am trying to find both the highest (lowest value) Start (B) and Finish (C) for both Constructors cars from the data in columns E,F and G

I have tried with MINIF as follows in CELL B2

=MINIFS(F:F,E:E,A2)

but this just returns 0

Is this possible to find both constructors ie Mercedes in E2 and E5 on populate B2 with the highest position  of 1 for these two team cars?

Thanks

Comment: either your "numbers" are stored as text, or there are spaces in the data that are not in the lookups.

Comment: @ScottCraner Boom that seems to be the problem, is it possible to convert the text to numeric format in the formula bar? only the data comes in from a json call like that :( Thanks

Comment: You can use Text to columns to convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ScottCraner for pointing out that my numbers were stored as text :)